# Access prototype from child object function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Suppose you have

```
function Thing () {
  this.val = 1;
}

Thing.prototype.some = function () {
  console.log('thing');
};

Thing.prototype.foo = {
  bar: function () {
    console.log(root.val);
  }
};
```

How would you be able to get a reference to `this` as in the `Thing` instance, while still sticking to a prototypal model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that setup, the only way to do it is to explicitly pass the object (the "Thing" instance) as a parameter, or use `.call()` or `.apply()`.

If you instantiate a "Thing":

```
var thing = new Thing();
```

then you can get to that "bar" function as `thing.foo.bar`.  Invoked from that reference:

```
thing.foo.bar();
```

the value of `this` inside "bar" will be the "foo" object on the prototype. You could however use `.call()`:

```
thing.foo.bar.call(thing);
```

then `this` in the invocation of "bar" will indeed be the instantiated "Thing" object.

It's important to keep in mind that, in JavaScript, setting an object property to a function does not create any kind of special relationship between the object and the function. What matters is the relationship(s) discovered when *referring* to property values in expressions. It's always dynamic, and while the mechanics of following the prototype chain are somewhat dizzying, the rules for how `this` is determined are pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function to a context without executing it like `call` / `apply` does. Use `bind`.

For example:

```
function Thing () {
  this.val = 1;
}

Thing.prototype.some = function () {
  console.log('thing');
};

Thing.prototype.foo = {
      bar: function () {
        console.log(this.val);
      }
  }

var thing = new Thing();
// bind instance's `foo.bar` to `thing` instance
thing.foo.bar = thing.foo.bar.bind( thing );
// now you can call it without providing `thing` as the context every time like wit apply/call
console.log( thing.foo.bar() );
```

It's event possible to bind `foo.bar` to an instance of Thing, but then every instance of Thing has `foo.bar` bound to a shared instance of Thing. I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but it kind of works:

```
function Thing () {
  this.val = 1;
}

Thing.prototype.some = function () {
  console.log('thing');
};

Thing.prototype.foo = {
      bar: function () {
        console.log(this.val);
      }.bind( new Thing() )
  }

var thing = new Thing();

console.log( thing.foo.bar() );
```

Comment: I guess the only way to really make it the way I wanted, then, would be to loop through those methods and `bind` in the constructor. Which is awful. Thanks